# Typescript with and without defenition files on the same namespace

Tags: typescript

I am running into a problem when using classes that have deninitions (base.d.ts) and some that do not and are just Typescript classes (EventDispatcher.ts) with the same namespace.

All in all i'm stuck between these errors as the following is not valid syntax:

```
declare var Acme.Ajax: AcmeAjaxInterface;
```

What i am trying to do:

My base.d.ts file contains:

```
interface AcmeInterface{
    Ajax: AcmeAjaxInterface;
}

interface AcmeAjaxInterface{
    call(...parameters: any[]);
}
```

my EventDispatcher.ts contains:

```
module Acme {
    expost class EventDispatcher{}
}
```

When trying to use both in the following file:

```
///<reference path="base.d.ts" />
///<reference path="EventDispatcher.ts" />
Acme.Ajax.Call():
```

I get an error because the Acme variable is never declared:

```
TS2094: The property 'Ajax' does not exist on value of type 'Acme'.
```

However, When i add the following:

```
declare var Acme : AcmeInterface;
```

I am getting an error:

```
TS2000: Duplicate identifier 'Acme'.
```

What would be the method to prevent these errors from happening?

Comment: Your TS2094 error is correct. 'Ajax' does not exist on value type of 'Acme'. At least that's what it looks like given the code sample you've provided. 

The TS2000 error is also correct. You've defined 'Acme' in two different places. 

It's a little difficult for me to understand what your ultimate goal is. Maybe I'm dumb, or maybe there's just not enough code here.

Comment: My ultimate goal is to prevent the TS2094 error by using some form of "declare var" on a namespace like:
declare var Acme.Ajax: AcmeAjaxInterface; (which is not valid syntax)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare var Acme.Ajax: AcmeAjaxInterface;
```

Should be

```
declare module Acme {
    export var Ajax: AcmeAjaxInterface;
}
```

You can't define/declare vars with .s in the name.  `module` is how you put things in a namespace.  Note that you can use .s as a shortcut to nested modules eg: `declare module Alpha.Bravo.Charlie { /*...*/ }`.

Comment: And so all of my errors magically vanished! Thanks you, very much. This was exactly what I was looking for!